# How can I make an image fall down randomly as if meteors in Corona SDK?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

What I want is that the images fall from the top side of the screen and start falling down accelerating, they would only be falling straight down, alternating positions around the width of the screen, meaning one on the right, then another one in the middle, and then another one on the left side and so on in the different positions, until they disappear at the bottom of the screen.

I tried this

```
function moveMeteors()
  for i = 1, math.random(1, 2) do 
    meteors = display.newImage("meteor.png")
    screenGroup:insert(meteors)
    meteors.x = (math.random(display.contentWidth))
    meteors.y = centerY - 340

    transition.to(meteors, {time = math.random(3500 - speedMeteor, 4500 - speedMeteor),
                            y = 1000 + speedMeteor, onComplete = clear })

    speedMeteor = speedMeteor + 10

  end
end
```

But, sometimes the images appear one over the other and I do not want that, I mean, each image appear and go from the top to the bottom of the screen in his own line. I hope that I've explained this well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into utilizing the built in physics of Coronasdk. [CoronaDocs:Physics.](http://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/api/library/physics/index.html)

As an example this code should easily simulate the effect you a trying to get, you will have to add functions to take care of removing objects as they leave the screen etc.

```
local physics = require("physics")
physics.start()

function SpawnMeteor()
    local meteor = display.newImage( "meteor.png", math.random(display.contentWidth), centerY - 340)
    physics.addBody( meteor)
end

timer.performWithDelay( 2000, SpawnMeteor)
```